# Retrieving a large dataset from a very large table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a very large table in oracle that contains 140+ million rows. Currently we are doing three full table scans on this table nightly, and using some of the results to populate a tmp table. That tmp table is then turned into a very large report (usually 140K + lines).

The big table is called tasklog and has the following structure has:
tasklog_id  (number)  - PK
document_id (number)
date_time_in   (date)
+ a few more rows that aren't relevant

There are millions of different document ids each repeated between 1 and several hundred times, date_time_in is the time this entry was put into the database.

All of the full table scans looks like this

```
DECLARE
n_prevdocid     number;

cursor tasks is
   select * 
   from tasklog
   order by document_id, date_time_in DESC;

BEGIN

for tk in tasks
loop
    if n_prevdocid <> tk.document_id then
         -- *code snipped*

    end if;
    n_prevdocid = tk.document_id;
end loop;

END;
/
```

So my question: is there a quick (ish) way to get a distinct list of document_ids with the row having the most recent date_time_in. This could dramatically speed up the whole thing. Or can anyone think of a better way of retrieving this data daily?

Things that may be relevant, this table only ever has rows inserted with current date time. It is not range paritioned but I can't see how that might help me. No rows are ever updated or deleted. There are about 70k - 80k rows inserted daily.

Comment: Currently thinking about range partitioning and multi threaded queries, but this could be tough as the threads wont use the same tmp table

Comment: as far as I understand you process only a fraction of rows. why do you full scan it?

Comment: I can't think of a way to get that fraction without a full scan. The rows I use are distributed over 13 years of data, each day I use a lot from the previous few days and a variable assortment from the previous years. There isn't a key on the rows I want. It does pull out about 140k rows in the end

Comment: Sou you need a list of document_ids for "today", which you will use to derive additional list from "previous few days/years", and the table's only index is on PK?

Comment: Not quite, I want the most recent entry for every distinct document_id in the table.

Comment: `select * from tasklog where rowid in (select max(rowid) keep (dense_rank first order by date_time_in desc) r from tasklog group by document_id)` - what's the query plan for this?

Comment: never mind, it will full-scan at least once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you're going to get away from doing at least one full table scan, as the only way that it would be efficient would be is if the ratio of distinct document_id's to total records was pretty small. The clustering on the document_id is going to be very poor due to the way that the data is generated and inserted.

How about:

```
create table tmp nologging compress -- or pctfree 0
as
select ...
from   (
  select t.*,
         max(date_time_in) over (partition by document_id) max_date_time_in
  from   tasklog t)
where   date_time_in = max_date_time_in
```

Possibly, having created this once, you could then optimise further refreshes by merging into this set only the newer records. Something like ...

```
merge into tmp
using (
  select ...
  from   (
    select t.*,
           max(date_time_in) over (partition by document_id) max_date_time_in
    from   tasklog t
    where  date_time_in > (select max(date_time_in) from tmp))
  where   date_time_in = max_date_time_in)
on ... blah blah
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of using the merge, combined with a partition on date range do you know if that will allow oracle to use multi threading to sort the data?

Comment: Parallelism you mean? Yes, but you probably wouldn't need it. In fact maybe the load of the data to the task log could be modified to also merge into your unique data set, or it could multi table insert into another table that you read in your merge process then truncate

Comment: Actually ignore that question, it shouldn't matter too much

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
select document_id
from tasklog t1
where date_time_in = (select max(date_time_in)
                      from tasklog t2
                      where t1.document_id=t2.document_id)
```

Comment: I don't think it will work as date_time_in is not necessarily unique

Comment: Also oracle has optimised it to use two full table scans on the tasklog table instead of one

Comment: I thought you wanted the most recent row per document_id. That's what this query does. If that can still return more than one row per document ID I don't know how to solve this. Which one should you select??
Also you might want to create an index on document_id and date_time_in.

Comment: There is an index on document_id and date_time_in. With a table this size oracle figures a full table scan is more efficient as there is no way to use the indexes well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`select document_id , date_time from tasklog group by date_time,document_id order by date_time desc;`

By this you can retrieve `distinct document_id` with latest `date_time` colums.

Comment: This table is massive (140 + million rows). I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use a full table scan. It will probably require something like partitions, indexes, views or multi threaded queries